# ext.js association not finished loading in time

Tags: javascript, extjs, associations

I have an association set up between my CostCenter and my Site Model.

My problem is that the association is not loaded in time when I try to display the Site in the CostCenterGrid.

```
 items: [
    {
        xtype: 'gridpanel',
        itemId: 'CostCenterGrid',
        columns: [
            {
                text: MR.locale.Name,
                dataIndex: 'Name',
                renderer: function(translation) {
                    return translation.get('ActualTranslation');
                },
                width: 150
            }, {
                text: MR.locale.Site,
                dataIndex: 'Site',
                renderer: function(value, meta, record) {
                    return record.getSite().get('ActualName');

                },
                width: 150
            },
        ],
        store: 'MR.store.administration.CostCenter',
    }
```

As you can see i have a Custom renderer for the site property. The first time I render the grid, the Site isn't display. When running it again the site is then correctly visible.

How to overcome this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Usually when you get such anomaly when things load at second time and such, it probably related to an Async processes.
I think that your record object is not ready or empty at first.
Make sure you get the data before you render it.

Comment: Yeah i know that the data is loaded async. I was wondering how i can achieve to wait for all stores to be loaded before rendering the grid.